# How to sum the alpha numeric column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column (attached below) which is having alpha numeric values for which I need to SUM all the values.

```
Percentage
----------
50.6687 percent
36.0178 percent
33.1196 percent
29.7688 percent
7.6338 percent
97.1024 percent
40.7949 percent
161.56 percent
```

I tried this code, but ended up with an error

```
SUM(CAST(S.FIELD_PERCENTAGE AS FLOAT)) OVER() [Sum of PERCENTAGE]
```

The error is

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 8
> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

How can I achieve this expected result:

```
Percentage         Sum of Percentage
----------         ----------------
50.6687 percent    456.666
36.0178 percent    456.666
33.1196 percent    456.666
29.7688 percent    456.666
7.6338 percent     456.666
97.1024 percent    456.666
40.7949 percent    456.666
161.56 percent     456.666
```

Comment: `50.6687 percent` is not a valid number, so in order to calculate with it, try `TRIM(REPLACE(S.FIELD_PERCENTAGE, 'percent', ''))`

Comment: Fix your design, stop storing numerical data as a string data type.

Comment: I highly recommend **not** using float for percentage values. Float is for scientific values and as such does not store all numbers accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`50.6687 percent` is not a valid number, so in order to calculate with it, try `TRIM(REPLACE(S.FIELD_PERCENTAGE, 'percent', ''))` in your CAST

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
FIELD_PERCENTAGE varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('50.6687 percent')
,('36.0178 percent')
,('33.1196 percent')
,('29.7688 percent')
,('7.6338 percent')
,('97.1024 percent')
,('40.7949 percent')
,('161.56 percent')

SELECT sum(cast(TRIM(REPLACE(S.FIELD_PERCENTAGE, 'percent', '')) AS FLOAT)) over() [Sum of PERCENTAGE]
  FROM @t s
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used the below combination and achieved the results.

```
SUM(CAST(REPLACE(S.FIELD_PERCENTAGE,'Percent','')AS FLOAT)) OVER() AS [Sum of Percentage],
```

Comment: @DaleK I have noted and upvoted all the answer which was useful.  I have shared mine which I have applied which could be useful. Can you please remove the downvote for my answer as I have shared the one which I applied that could be useful for reference.